# Using JBoss DROOLS XMLDumper with .dslr file

Tags: jboss, dsl, drools

I have a .dslr file consiting of a rule(dslr) and a dsl file. I need to get the XML output of the DRL from this dslr.

I've tried different ways with the XMLDumper but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your DSLR file to DRL, then do the same as before. See following link for an example on how to convert DSLR to DRL:

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/DrlParserTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I repackaged the unit test above into a command line utility, handy for debugging.

**Dslr2Drl.java**

```
package org.drools.compiler;

// Based on:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280068
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402545
// http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/DrlParserTest.java

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

/***
// Include these if using Injected Expander
import org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException;
import org.drools.lang.Expander;
import org.drools.lang.dsl.DSLMappingFile;
import org.drools.lang.dsl.DSLTokenizedMappingFile;
import org.drools.lang.dsl.DefaultExpander;
import org.drools.lang.dsl.DefaultExpanderResolver;
***/

public class Dslr2Drl {
    public static String readFileAsString( String inFileName ) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileName), "UTF-8"));
        while( true ) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if ( null==line ) {
                break;
            }
            buff.append( line ).append( "\r\n" );
        }
        in.close();
        return new String( buff );
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DroolsParserException, IOException {
        if ( 2 != args.length ) {
            System.err.println( "syntax: Dslr2Drl sentences.dslr transform.dsl > output.drl" );
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // String dslr = "rule 'foo' \n when \n Something \n then \n another \nend";
        String dslr = readFileAsString( args[0] );
        // String dsl = "[condition]Something=Something()\n[then]another=another();";
        String dsl = readFileAsString( args[1] );
        // String expect = "rule 'foo' \n when \n Something() \n then \n another(); \nend";

        DrlParser parser = new DrlParser();
        String result = parser.getExpandedDRL( dslr, new StringReader(dsl) );
        System.out.println( result );

        /***
        // Using Injected Expander
        DefaultExpanderResolver resolver = new DefaultExpanderResolver(new StringReader(dsl));
        final DSLMappingFile file = new DSLTokenizedMappingFile();
        if ( file.parseAndLoad( new StringReader(dsl) ) ) {
            final Expander expander = new DefaultExpander();
            expander.addDSLMapping( file.getMapping() );
            resolver.addExpander("*", expander);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeDroolsException( "Error parsing and loading DSL file." + file.getErrors() );
        }
        DrlParser parser = new DrlParser();
        String result = parser.getExpandedDRL( drl, resolver);
        ***/
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a project on Github that includes a prebuilt self-contained JAR file, https://github.com/ttennebkram/dslr2drl, see target/dslr2drl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar