# JBOSS DROOLS using XmlDumper with .dslr

Tags: xml, jboss, dsl, drools

I am able to parse a .DRL file into the XmlDumper and get the correct output. How I can I pass a .DSLR file through the XmlDumper to achieve the same results? The .DSLR file contains the language file(.DSL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your DSLR file to DRL, then do the same as before.  See following link for an example on how to convert DSLR to DRL:

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/DrlParserTest.java

Kris

Comment: @JackSmith fyi I repackaged the unit test above into a command line utility, handy for debugging.  See Dslr2Drl.java in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17891806/295802

Comment: I put a project on Github that includes a prebuilt self-contained JAR file, https://github.com/ttennebkram/dslr2drl, see target/dslr2drl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar